# Using two tables or single table with multiple rows?

Tags: django

( This is for Django ) I have two functions one is used for "requesting documents" (it can be more than 3) and another function is "Sending documents" (it also can be more than 2)

Now my problem is both has various purpose, so should i need to create two table or single table with a differentiation ?

How to handle this efficiently ?

**Option1: Create two table named "RequestedDocuments" & "SendDocuments" and save accordingly or**

**Option2: Create a single table named "Documents" and have field named "Type" and save accordingly with some types like "request" & "send"?****

My another concern is, In one of the view i need to show all the two in separate tables and in another view i need to show only one of the above ! So which is more efficient ?

Comment: IMO I'd good go with one table, So dont have to query on 2 tables and merge queryset. To show only one of them you can filter them with type.

One disadvantage I can think of it that You have very few document of one type(let say SendDocuments) and you want to get only those documents, at that time it is not efficient to keep both in single table.

Comment: if its more than 5 documents of request and 5 documents of send then it would be 10 rows of data ! And will the be inefficient in long run ? Am even considering using a arrayField for cataching all documents !

Comment: I think It will be efficient to get 10 in single query than 5/5 in two query.

Comment: How about arrayField and holding all required document in a single array field ?

Comment: umm i think it will become harder to query on them

Comment: If the Documents are for the rest identical, I would keep them in one table, with a field called `type` to distinguish between the two. If you worry about performance fetching only one kind, add the following to the model: `db_index=True`.

If the Documents look completely different, then of course they represent different things and should end up in two different tables.

Comment: Wont primary key will be automatically indexed ? why we need db_index ? @physicalattraction

Comment: Your primary key will indeed be automatically indexed, but we are talking here about an additional field (`type`) with the values `Requested` or `Sent` which needs to define this index.